# My magento Website Speed is too low

Tags: magento-1.9

my website is http://www.feetheart.com/magento/ and I'm using intenso magento theme and there are 5000 skus my website is speed is too low, can anyone have solutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing Magento site for speed is a process which takes time and effort. It requires lots of tuning and optimizations. There is no one size fits all solution. To start with, you can go to [**google pagespeed insights**](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) page and put your site's url there and press submit. It will show suggestions for improvement in different categories. Like:
**Enable compression (gzip), Optimze images, Leverage Browser caching, Use Content delivery network (CDN) to deliver images,css and js files** etc..

Once you are done with client side performance optimization, you can go for the server side speed optimizations like:

You can choose to integrate [**Redis**](http://inchoo.net/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/) caching instead of file based session and caching related things.
Then you can put [**<strike>Varnish</strike>**](http://www.blinkdata.com/install-varnish-to-make-magento-1000-times-faster/) in front of Apache server to offload lots of static content (Move Apache on port 8080 and integrate Varnish on port 80).

If you will implement all this, you will definitely get your site running at more than 200-300% faster than it is right now.

And the world doesn't end here, have you heard about [**mod_pagespeed**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-mod_pagespeed-with-apache-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server), [**cloudflare**](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203904600-Using-CloudFlare-with-Magento) etc?

Comment: I have tried with flat categories and products enable, completion enables, cache all the categories enable,full cache enable,log system on, but not getting speed, also tried with cloudfare, it's not working with my site.

Any other solutions for increasing speed?

Thanks,
Hiral